# Variable re-assign method result if not Nil

Tags: raku, syntactic-sugar

Is there idiomatic way of applying and assigning object variable method call, but only if it's defined (both method and the result)?

Like using [safe call operator `.?`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-methodop_.%3F) and [defined-or operator `//`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_//), and with "DRY principle" – using the variable only once in the operation?

Like this (but using another variable feels like cheating):

```raku
my $nicevariable = "fobar";

# key step
(my $x := $nicevariable) = $x.?possibly-nonexistent-meth // $x;

say $nicevariable;  # => possibly-nonexistent-meth (non-Nil) result or "foobar"
```

... And avoiding `andthen`, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "using the variable only once in the operation".  If Liz's answer qualifies, then it's probably the cleaner way to go.

If not, here's a different approach that avoids naming the variable twice:

```
my $nicevariable = "foobar";
$nicevariable.=&{.^lookup('possibly-nonexistent-meth')($_)}
```

This is a bit too cryptic for my tastes; here's what it does: If the method exists, then that's similar to¹ calling `&method($nicevariable)`, which is the same as `$nicevariable.method`.  If the method does *not* exist, then it's like calling `Mu($nicevariable)` – that is, coercing `$nicevariable` into `Mu` or a subtype of `Mu`.  But since everything is already a subtype of `Mu`, that's a no-op and just returns `$nicevariable`.

[1]: Not quite, since `&method` would be a Sub, but basically.

**EDIT**:

Actually, that was over-complicating things.  Here's a simpler version:

```
my $nicevariable = "foobar";
$nicevariable.=&{.?possibly-nonexistent-meth // $_}
```

Not sure why I didn't just have that to begin with…

Comment: The edit is very very close to what I meant... I was playing with `.=`, but the `&` trick did not occur to me, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Are you aware of the [default trait](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/trait%20is%20default) on variables?

Not sure if it fits your use case, but `$some-var.?unknown-method` returns Nil, so:

```
my $nicevariable is default("fobar");
$nicevariable = $nicevariable.?possibly-nonexistent-meth;
say $nicevariable;  # fobar
```

results in `$nicevariable` being reset to its default value;

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the method returns something that *is* defined, you could do (if I'm understanding the question correctly):

```
my $x = "foobar";
$x = $_ with $y.?possibly-nonexistent-meth;
```

`$x` will remain unchanged if the method didn't exist (or it *did* exist and returned a type object).

Comment: (You probably did mean `$x` instead of `$y`.)

Comment: Interesting. I did not yet get, how it passes my non-Nil condition....

Comment: .. probably by the definition :) (the `with` name is not very descriptive)

Comment: If I didn't want to overwrite the variable and to "mention" it only once in the key line, it would probably be THE way to go.

Comment: @mykhal re `$y` vs `$x`: you tell me :-)  It wasn't clear to me from the example code.

Comment: My example uses one additional 1-letter helper variable to demonstrate one of reasons why I want to avoid "double usage" of the target variable with long name. I really don't get your 3rd variable "$y" resulting in invalid code.

Answer (score 4):

As of [this merge](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4492) you can write:

```
try { let $foo .= bar }
```

---

This is a step short of what I think would have been an ideal solution, which is unfortunately a syntax error (due to a pervasive weakness in Raku's *current* grammar that I'm guessing is effectively unsolvable, much as I would love it to be solved):

```
{ let $foo .?= bar } # Malformed postfix call...
```

(Perhaps I'm imagining things, but I see a glimmer of hope that the above wrinkle (and many like it) will be smoothed over a few years from now. This would be after RakuAST lands for Raku `.e`, and the grammar gets a hoped for clean up in Raku `.f` or `.g`.)

---

Your question's *title* is:

> Variable re-assign method result if not `Nil`

My solution does a variable re-assign method if not *undefined*, which is more general than just `Nil`.

Then again, your question's *body* asks for exactly that more general solution:

> Is there idiomatic way of applying and assigning object variable method call, but only if it's defined (both method and the result)?

So is my solution an ideal one?

My solution is not *idiomatic*. But that might well be because of the bug I found, now solved with the merge linked at the start of my answer. I see no reason why it should not *become* idiomatic, once it's in shipping Rakudos.

The potentially big issue is that the `try` stores any exception thrown in `$!` rather than letting it blow up. Perhaps that's OK for a given use case; perhaps not.

---

Special thanks to you for asking your question, which prompted us to come up with various solutions, which led me to file an issue, which led vrurg to both analyse the problem I encountered and then fix it. :)

Comment: I like this version – especially because you still have access to any disarmed exception / failure in `$!`, which could preserve your option to handle some.

Comment: Please note that depending on the `.bar` methods contents, you have no guarantee that `$foo` will actually remain unchanged, even if some exception occurred.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I know some methods may begin to mutate their invocant and then throw, or throw and then `.resume`, but I presume you don't mean that (it would be an issue with codesection's answer too). I'm fuzzy about the precise details of bailing out of executing a statement when an exception is thrown, but it surprises me to hear `try` would fail to immediately bail out of an assignment or binding statement (`let` or any other) if an exception is thrown when evaluating the rhs. If that's what you mean, could you link to something I could read about that? TIA.

Comment: @raiph I'm not sure what you could read about that.  Assignment is really nothing different from setting an attribute in an object.  If that happens before an execution error, it will stay set.  Unless you have a UNDO phaser that does something to undo that setting.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen "Assignment is really nothing different from setting an attribute in an object." Right. "If that happens before an execution error, it will stay set." Even a `let`?!? Consider `my Int @array = 1, 2; try { let @array = (42 and die) }; try { let @array = 3, 'a' }; .say for $!, @array; # Type check failed in assignment ... got Str ("a")␤[1 2]␤`. The first `try` throws at the end of evaluating the `let`'s rhs. The second throws *during* the assignment of the `let`'s *lhs*. Yet the end result in *both* cases is that `@array` is left unchanged. What scenario am I missing?